# Splicing two-wire and three-wire cable

Tags: electrical

While splicing cable what happens if you connect the black wire (hot from supply) on a 12-2 wire to both the red and black on a 12-3 wire?

[image]

Understanding this isn't to code, I'm looking for what would normally happen, on a normal 15A or 20A breaker. Would this work? Is it inherently unsafe? Could this easily start issues on the circuit that might cause a fire, burn out outlets/appliances etc?

Comment: Why do you want to do this, instead of simply capping off the red wire at both ends?

Comment: If this is a 15A breaker, ignore (cap both ends) the red. If this is a 20A breaker, **not allowed** because (a) paralleling isn't allowed for ordinary circuits and, even if you could, you would need to parallel the white neutral as well, because it carries just as much current as the hot wire(s).

Comment: ThreePhaseEel, Who said I wanted to do this? Why couldn't I just be curious or have encountered this somewhere? I wasn't justifying it, I was asking what would happen, if you don't know, don't answer; it's that simple.

Comment: @corey_borders In regular human communication, usually when someone asks a question it's with intent to act (or, having already acted, is asking under the veil of not yet having done it!). No need to get defensive - you're on a DIY site which is prone to _a lot_ of questions of the form "So, I decided best would be to X, what happens when I X?". Especially around things that can catch fire or seriously injure someone, sometimes the best course of action is to yell "STOP, DON'T!" to deter passerby's other than yourself... :)

Comment: @corey_borders this is a place where people ask questions in order to **solve a problem**. If you do not have a problem then a discussion forum would be a better place for this. "*what would happen*" Nothing good and a long list of possible bad things could happen.

Answer (score 7):

It's paralleling, which is itself bad for a variety of reasons relating to EMFs, eddy currents and other behavior-of-AC arcana.

But mostly, it's bad because of what *the next guy* might do with it.  Some part of the rules is about people doing work that's consistent enough that the next person has a chance of understanding it (e.g. if re-tasking white to a hot, you must make it the *always-hot* if possible, so the next guy is more likely to detect its hotness). Obviously "the next guy" might only open up one box here, and be confused or do something stupid with it.

Answer (score 0):

> what happens if you connect the black wire (hot from supply) on a 12-2 wire to both the red and black on a 12-3 wire?

you make a parallel conductor

> would it work

yes

> Is it inherently unsafe?

no.  If it was, then we would never have parallel conductors, anywhere.  And the NEC 366.20 *Conductors Connected in Parallel* would be all wrong, along with whatever section 300.x about parallel conductors being allowed... under specific situations.

> Could this easily start issues on the circuit that might cause a fire, burn out outlets/appliances etc

easily, no. not on a 15 or 20 amp circuit.

Instead of paralleling the conductor, simply wire cap it off on each end and leave it unused if you have 12/3 and just want to use that and not have to go get 12/2.  There's no *good* reason to parallel a conductor on residential amperage less than 100/200 amp.  Parallel conductors come around when you have 500+ amp feeders and you can't have a single 20/0 conductor 1 foot in diameter or whatever it mathematically comes out to, realistically it comes down to where you can't pull or install big feeders in the dimensions available.  So you get what is reasonably available X/0 wire and you parallel them to meet the amperage needs of that situation.  And per code it's no wire smaller than 1/0.  Feeder(s) to a building, or feeder(s) to your light switch, electricity doesn't necessarily care what the load is.

https://www.ecmag.com/section/codes-standards/conductors-connected-parallel-each-set-must-have-same-electrical

https://iaeimagazine.org/magazine/features/parallel-conductors-revisited/

https://www.electricallicenserenewal.com/Electrical-Continuing-Education-Courses/NEC-Content.php?sectionID=297.0

Comment: Not quite.  Your rationale is that if paralleling were unsafe, 366.20 would not exist.  *You're overlooking that 366.20 has particular requirements, partly that **special equipment must be used***. I can understand why you missed this regulatory sleight of hand, because it punts the particulars over into the UL White Book, which isn't free.  The upshot is that paralleled wires must be individually fused.

Comment: is it **inherently** unsafe, no.  Could paralleling **easily** start issues... under the context of the question no.   *I'm looking for what would normally happen...*  Chastising for asking any kind of electrical question that dares give any hint of bucking the almighty NEC require independent thought.

Comment: @ corey, a question like you ask simply does not belong in this diy wild west home improvement forum, answers are based on interpretation of the NEC that's it and don't think any further than that.  You need to ask this in the Electrical Engineering section to possibly get a rational answer to such a question, I think your question simply does not belong here based on that mentality and it's not your fault for asking.

Comment: I come here for the entertainment and to sometimes see how much I can get down voted.  Your question was actually a good question, shame you couldn't get good answers for it.

Comment: *rolls eyes* There's that old trope that the NEC sit around dreaming up stupid rules for ??? reason other than safety, and therefore that makes it OK for you to ignore any rule you please. That's incorrect.  ...... We have a simple rule here: if you're going to deviate from Code, you need to explain why Code doesn't make sense here, *which requires understanding why it does make sense in its normal use*.  You refuse to possess that knowledge, because that would require admitting NEC is actually pretty well designed.  If you think following rules is "wild west", then wow.